# Convert comma delimited, key-value pairs in single column into different columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, csv

I have a column in an excel sheet that contains value formatted like the following:

```
"Key1":"Value1","Key2":"Value2","Key3":"Value3"..
```

I have many rows of this data. I would like to break these keys out into their own columns with the corresponding values in the appropriate rows. Something like below:

```
Key1  | Key2 | Key3
------|------|------
Value1|Value2|Value3
```

How would I best go about this in Excel?

Notes:

- The keys will not change much between rows, however the values will be different
- This must be done within Excel due to the fact that the data is a scheduled report and we have no control over how the source is providing the data

Comment: *I have a column in an excel sheet that contains value formatted like the following* Does this whole string is stored in one cell? *Something like below* Does this is two separate rows and three columns?

Comment: I would write a VBA routine, using a dictionary object with the "keys" as the key, and the "values" as a collection or array of the associated values.  Then output it however you want on the worksheet.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Would you happen to either have a sample or be able to point me in the correct direction? :)

Comment: Doing a search for Dictionary of collections should get you started. There are a bunch of examples on Stackoverflow although I don't know about SuperUser. You might also be able to do it with PowerQuery, but it won't work in Excel 2007 as it only became a part of Excel with 2010 (at that time, as a free add-in from Microsoft).

Answer (score 1):

if a solution outside of excel is accepted, you can just copy everything to txt file, replace the entry separator (,) with newline (crlf), then paste it back to excel and use the built-in text-to-columns option for the key-value separator (:)
then you have two columns key and value. mark the columns and copy it, use the paste special option and select transpose

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

Comment: ... plus transpose.

Comment: you are right. because key and value are columns after paste. It has to be transposed. I will update answer thanks

Comment: That will not work because outside of Excel this entire file is actually a CSV and there is more than this single column in the file. Performing this work within Excel is a requirement.

Comment: have you tried? CSV is a txt file, just open it and do the replacements, than import

Comment: Performing this in Excel is a requirement due to the fact that the data comes from an external source and a macro/function is needed to format the data each time a new CSV from the source is loaded. There is no control over the source.

Comment: ok. if you like, you can update your question with this comment. sure there are vba freaks here they will help

Comment: @alecxs Updated with clarification, thanks! Now to find some VBA freaks..

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you could do the following:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<Group><colon>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("$A"&(ROUNDUP(ROW()/2,0))),":","</colon><comma>"),",","</comma><colon>")&"</comma></Group>",IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,"/Group/colon","/Group/comma")))
```

This divides the values into two rows, so you need two output rows for every row in your source data. That makes it seem odd-ish, I suppose, but it's what you seem to envision. So row 1's data comes out in rows 1 and 2, row 2's data in rows 3 and 4, and so on.

If you really wanted all the data rows in one very wide two row display, you could concatenate all the data rows into one data row. That would work best with `TEXTJOIN()` as it lets you set a delimiter that only falls BETWEEN the elements, while `CONCAT()` can have a delimiter attached to the end (`CONCAT(A1:A14)&","` would be the approach) but then you have to strip the one at the end off in some easy, but extra, manner.

So, what's in the formula? Two `SUBSTITUTE()` functions are chained (one wrapped around the other). One changes the colons to an HTML tag set and the other changes the commas to an HTML tag set. This is a fairly common thing now, using `FILTERXML()` to break apart a string (OR array constant, like created with `TEXTJOIN()`), but this is kinda different than the regular use.

Usually, you use the substitution process to insert a closing tag and an opening tag for the delimiters, then prepend the opening tags before the string and append the closing tags after the string. So the tags before the string open the tag set around the first element, then the substitution there puts the closing tag and a new opening tag for the next element. That happens all along the string until at the end, there is an open tag and the stuff you append at the end closes that. So it might look like so if you pasted values:

```
`<element>SOMETHING_IN_THE_STRING</element>` (and then more of these)
```

Anyway, you have to have an HTML tag structure with at least two "levels" for this to work. Like a directory structure, so I use `Group` for the overall, top level tag set, and `Element` for the elements of the string. Reasonably logical. Others use simply `a` and `b` to cut down on the typing, and other have ideas that makes sense to them or their material. Anyway, that two level structure is called the `Path` by the function's Intellisense help and that's a good analogy.

So you get that string built to feed to `FILTERXML()` and also you tell it the `Path`, then it works like a charm. You can even add a teensy bit to each use of the formula to get a particular element, maybe the 7th element in the string. That's outside the scope of this, but handy to know.

The thing is, WHY? WHY do you need a `Path`? It's obvious from the construction of the string what the path is! The high level element is the tag at the beginning and the end and the low level element is the tag (tags, more likely) in between. How hard is that?

Well, Excel meant this to be used on actual website-type HTML in which a hundred tag sets might be being used. Not for this purpose. Now it makes sense, but it also suggests you can do two things at once, not just one.

And you DO need to do two things at once here.

So, you see the high level tag set:  Group. And TWO low level tag sets:  colon and comma. That means if you can mark things appropriately, you can use the one string building portion to extract two completely separate arrays of string elements.

Usually you see the inner substitution replace something like commas with something like `</Element><Element>` (closing tag, opening tag, but the same tag). Here you need opposite pairs, as you see in the formula, to close one element's tag and open thee other's, back and forth. Everything else you do needs to be consistent with that. If you look at the formula, you'll see how, no problema.

So, now that you have an overall high level tag set and two low level tag sets inside it, you can use an `IF()` to pass one `Path` or the other to `FILTERXML()`. It tests whether the formula is in the odd row of the pair (giving the first half of all pairs in the string, if so) or the even row of the pair (giving the second half of all pairs in the string, if so). So if the string is `1:2,3:4`, the first row of the pair gives `1,3` and the second row gives `2,4`.

`FILTERXML()` likes to output a column, so `TRANSPOSE()` turns it into the rows you desire.

`SPILL` functionality gives you a full set in each row without needing `{CSE}` entry, yay! That fills the rows. But the various things I tried for getting it to `SPILL` down as many rows as would be needed — automatically — failed as they all refused to deal with the internal arrays. The solution to that is usually to use another function, compatible with the desired output, to force it to, but I ran out of time. Something will work, but it's give this answer or no answer so...

In any case, copy the formula down as many cells in the output region as needed, two rows per row in the source data. The formulas in them will give you the needed output which you can then use however.